# Get ID of element clicked

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
function getElement(e) {
    var element = e.target || e.srcElement;
    alert(element.id);
}
</script>

</head>
<body onclick="getElement()">

<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Tried this to get the ID of element clicked and alert it.
I'm sure it's something pretty basic I'm missing.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Check the console for errors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's actually pretty basic, stop using inline event handlers

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <title>It works</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="div1"></div>
        <div id="div2"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                alert( e.target.id );
            }, false);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/hhgkct48/)

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case, you need to actually send in the `event` object when binding to the `onclick` handler (example below).

**However, I would strongly advise against using this approach!**

Use `document.addEventListener` instead.

```html
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
function getElement(e) {
    var element = e.target || e.srcElement;
    alert(element.id);
}
</script>

</head>
<body onclick="getElement(event)">

<div id="div1">First Div</div>
<div id="div2">Second Div</div>

</body>
</html>
```