# Play audio onclick (when I click on an image)

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, audio

I have a school project and I've run into a issue. I made a website that contains simple table, searchable with AJAX. I have image of the person in one column and audio in the second one. What I want to do is when I click on the image it plays audio, and I've successfully done that. The issue is that it's only playing first audio, no matter what picture I click on. So if I click on image in line 5, it will play audio from line 1, and not from line 5 as it should.
[Click to see how the table looks.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXi8C.png)

This is part of the code in php:

```
while($redak = mysqli_fetch_array($rezultat)) {
echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $redak['id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $redak['ime'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $redak['prezime'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $redak['adresa'] . "</td>";
echo "<td> <img onclick=\"play()\" src=\"Slike/" . $redak['slika1'] . "\"</td>";
  echo "<td> <audio controls id=\"audio\" src=\"Audio/" . $redak['slika'] . "\"</td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

This is code for audio play onclick in javascript:

```
function play() {
    var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
    audio.play();
  }
```

Comment: This answers here will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49200511/how-do-i-get-the-id-of-clicked-element-using-pure-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Your id seems to be constant in your loop, so all your audio tags currently have the same id,

you could do something like:

```
    $id = "audio";
    $id .= $redak['id'];
    echo "<td> <img onclick=\"play($id)\" src=\"Slike/" . $redak['slika1'] . "\"</td>";
    echo "<td> <audio controls id=\"$id\" src=\"Audio/" . $redak['slika'] . "\"</td>
```

then your javascript function would be:

```
 function play(id){
  var audio = document.getElementById(id);
  audio.play();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that all created `<audio>` tags have the same id, that's why your `play` function selects the first audio file and play it...

you can modify both of your `<img>` and `<audio`> tag inside while statement to something like this:

```php
while($redak = mysqli_fetch_array($rezultat)) {
    // ....

    echo "<td> <img onclick=\"play('audio_" . $redak['id'] . "')\" src=\"Slike/" . $redak['slika1'] . "\"</td>";

    echo "<td> <audio controls id=\"audio_" . $redak['id'] . "\" src=\"Audio/" . $redak['slika'] . "\"</td>";
    // ....
}
```

also you have to change `play()` function to receive the audio id

```
function play(audio_id) {
    var audio = document.getElementById(audio_id);
    audio.play();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's more than one issue here. First, you never close the `<img>` and `<audio>` tags. The second issue is that you're reusing the same `id` on all the audio tags, which is invalid in HTML. `id`'s *must* be unique within a document.

I would also recommend not echoing blocks of HTML like you're doing since it makes it harder to spot issues with the HTML.

Change your loop like this:

```
<?php
while($redak = mysqli_fetch_array($rezultat)) 
{
    $id = 'audio_' . $redak['id'];
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $redak['id'] ?></td>
        <td><?= $redak['ime'] ?></td>
        <td><?= $redak['prezime'] ?></td>
        <td><?= $redak['adresa'] ?></td>
        <td><img onclick="play('<?= $id ?>')" src="Slike/<?= $redak['slika1'] ?>" /></td>
        <td><audio controls id="<?= $id ?>" src="Audio/<?= $redak['slika'] ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
```

Then change your JS to:

```
function play(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).play();
}
```