# How do I know which button was clicked in the Google Apps script?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, events, web-applications

When I have the following buttons in Google Apps Script html

```html
<button id="movie" onclick="getMovie()">get Movie List</button>
<button id="music" onclick="getMusic()">get Music List</button>
```

How do I know which button is clicked in Google Apps Script?
I tried using `localStorage.getItem`, but the gs file did not recognize `localStorage`.
Can I import the value of the clicked button **without using the event parameter?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get ID of element clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28444457/get-id-of-element-clicked)

Comment: `without using the event parameter?` Why?

Comment: @TheMaster It was because I wanted to use the function I was trying to use without receiving the parameter.
The problem has been resolved well. Thank you.

Comment: @Kos It's a little different, but the problem has been solved well. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever method that you use to get call a function on client-side, you might have to communicate with the server-side code using `google.script.run`, i.e. `google.script.run.myFunction(id)`.

Since the event object is automatically generated, it doesn't make sense to avoid its use but it's possible by using `this` as the function parameter used as the value of the `onclick` attribute.

Note: Using onclick attribute, while it's still supported, it's is discouraged by the design principle "[separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)". See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these for a specific explanation.

Here is client-side only sample of using `this` as explained above:

```js
function getMovie(a){
  console.log(a.id)
}

function getMusic(b){
  console.log(b.id)
}
```

```html
<button id="movie" onclick="getMovie(this)">get Movie List</button>
<button id="music" onclick="getMusic(this)">get Music List</button>
```

Related

- [How does the "this" keyword work, and when should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/1595451)

Answer (score 1):

You can make a generic function and then pass the object that the onclick function is associated with `this`.

Here is an example.

**HTML_Test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="movie" onclick="buttonClick(this)">get Movie List</button>
    <button id="music" onclick="buttonClick(this)">get Music List</button>
    <script>
      function buttonClick(button) {
        alert("You clicked "+button.id);
        google.script.run.getButton(button.id);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Code.gs**

```
function getButton(id) {
  Logger.log("You pressed "+id);
}
```

**Execution log**

```
Oct 6, 2022, 7:17:00 AM Info    You pressed movie
```