# how to get id of element when clicking it

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a function that gets the ID of the element clicked. For example the button

```
<button id="test" onclick="getElementId();"> Test </button>
```

I thought about using *this* to get the function running

```
<script>
    function getElementId(){
    var x = document.getElementById(this).getAttribute('id');
    }
</script>
```

But the console keeps saying
*"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getAttribute')
at getElementId ((Index):83:48)
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((Index):80:52)"*

I get, that *this* returns empty.

Comment: Or this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28444457/get-id-of-element-clicked

Comment: Or this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49200511/how-do-i-get-the-id-of-clicked-element-using-pure-javascript

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById(this)` will won't work,you can try with below

```js
function getElementId(obj){
  console.log(obj.id)
}
```

```html
<button id="test" onclick="getElementId(this);"> Test </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `this` object inside your `getElementId` function is bound to the `window` object or undefined depending on the stric mode option.

Pass the clicked `this` to the `getElementId` function. And inside the function you can use the argument to get the Id of the button.

```
<button id="test" onclick="getElementId(this);"> Test </button>
<script>
    function getElementId(element){
        var x = element.getAttribute('id');
    }
</script>
```